# C# Invalid Literal Characters

Tags: c#, regex

I created a working PCRE regex (for looking for PO Box address entries) that is throwing parser errors in C#.

The error is because of "\." and "\s" characters in my pattern.

The error is: "Invalid literal character"

**Here is the regex**

```
^(?!.*p\.?o\.?\s+?box).*$
```

**Here is the implementation**

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!.*p\.?o\.?\s+?box).*$", ErrorMessage = "We cannot ship to PO boxes")]
```

Would someone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Technically that's not PCRE, although it uses the same syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This because of backslash. Put your regex  as verbatim string literal. Single backslash inside double quotes would be treated as a escape sequence.

```
@"^(?!.*p\.?o\.?\s+?box).*$"
```

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

Comment: More context needed, the @ symbol tells the compiler to treat it as a literal, just saying because of backslash isn't really a suitable answer

Answer (score 1):

Because the backslash is treated as escape character you either need to give your string as verbatim string:

```
@"^(?!.*p\.?o\.?\s+?box).*$"
```

Or you need to put two backslashes instead of one like following:

```
"^(?!.*p\\.?o\\.?\\s+?box).*$"
```